# Declare a struct in a header file to be accessed and filled by a .cc file

Tags: c++

I am trying to define a structure in a header file such that it can be used later by different .cc files.

The header where I'm defining the class is the following:

```
#ifndef test_h
#define test_h

class test
{

public:
struct TestStruct
{
    Float_t var1_;
    Float_t var2_;
    Float_t var3_;
} myStruct_;

};


#endif
```

In the .cc file I include the header file and I am trying to access the variables of this structure in order to fill them with values as follows:

```
test::myStruct_.var1_ = value1;
test::myStruct_.var2_ = value2;
...
```

When doing this, I get the following compiler error:

```
test.h:23:3:error: invalid use of member 'test::myStruct_' in static member function

test.cc:449:39: error: from this location
```

Where the location in the second error is the place where the variable is accessed.

As far as I understood from some other posts I saw, I would have to somehow make the .cc file aware of the existence of this structure defined in test.h.

I tried several ways:

```
TestStruct* test::myStruct_;

myStruct_ = test::TestStruct;
```

But I just get compilation errors...

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by trying to access the `myStruct_` member of class `test` without having an actual instance of the class. One way to do this properly would be to declare an instance of `test` on the stack inside a function, like this:

```
test instance;
instance.myStruct_.var1_ = value1;
instance.myStruct_.var2_ = value2;
instance.myStruct_.var3_ = value3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not instantiated an object  "test" is a type of class, not an instantiation of a class. Try this:

```
test myTest;
myTest.myStruct_.var1_ = value;
```